create report in power bi embedded
I am using the demo example for powerbi-client-react: https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-client-react
I've added a onCreate() function to generate a new report but running into this 'no create support' error. Is there another approach that should be taken to create new reports?

const [report, setReport] = useState();

const onCreate = () => {
   report.create()
}


    <PowerBIEmbed
      embedConfig={sampleReportConfig}
      eventHandlers={eventHandlersMap}
      cssClassName={'report-container'}
      getEmbeddedComponent={(embedObject) => {
        setReport(embedObject);
      }}
    />


If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

There is no method as report.create() to create a Power BI Reports.
Power BI Embedded allows us to create, edit and save reports. Please note that, a report can be created in powerbi-embedded only if we have an existing dataset. Refer to this documentation on how to create, edit and save reports in powerbi-embedded.
Create Report Embed has been introduced in latest powerbi-client-react version. It's the same way how we embed the Report, instead the props embedConfig should be of type IReportCreateConfiguration.

Hi thank you for your response. Do you have the link for generating the embed url to be used in the embedConfig? I can't seem to find it in the documentation

Here is the REST API documentation link to get the Embed URL
